# iOS Barcode Scanner

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I'm interested in creating an app that uses the camera as a barcode scanner. I have a vague idea as to what I must do but no idea as to how or if i'm right.

I know it entails image processing, to analyse the barcode itself (white spaces/blackspaces), maybe some image framing to get it right, but no idea as to how to start.

Can you point me in the right direction?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might take a look at [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).  It is a free, open source implementation of barcode scanning based on image processing.  It was originally written for the Android platform, but portions have been ported to various other platforms and it could at least be a reference guide on how to do this type of thing.